# How to enable use of minus and plus in tex documents?

Tags: calculations, lengths

I see many `cls` files using `plus` and `minus` operators to set lengths. How can I use these operators (or some equivalent macro(s)) to do something like the following?

```
\setlength{\lengtha}{.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\lengthb}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\lengtha plus \lengthb}{cc}
a & b \\
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: The `plus` and `minus` operators that you see in `cls` and other files describe examples of stretchable glue. You can find many descriptions of it, [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32193/globally-set-paragraph-top-and-bottom-margins) has a good example and explanation to get you started :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [calc](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) package. Package description:

> Adds infix expressions to perform arithmetic on the arguments of the LaTeX commands `\setcounter`, `\addtocounter`, `\setlength`, and `\addtolength`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\lengtha}
\setlength{\lengtha}{.5\textwidth}
\newlength{\lengthb}
\setlength{\lengthb}{.5\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{\lengtha + \lengthb}{cc}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks -- this is also convenient. Seems like it cannot be used in all places though (for instance, setting a new length in a list environment...), but will keep in mind.

Answer (score 16):

To perform simple arithmetic operations with lengths you can use the e-TeX primitive `\dimexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\lengtha}
\setlength{\lengtha}{.5\textwidth}
\newlength{\lengthb}
\setlength{\lengthb}{.5\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\dimexpr\lengtha+\lengthb\relax}{cc}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

For further details, please refer to the [e-TeX manual](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/etex_man.pdf).

Something different is the use of `plus` and `minus` to specify glue in TeX:

```
<dimen>plus<dimen>minus<dimen>
```

where the `plus<dimen>` and `minus<dimen>` are optional and set to zero if not present; `plus` introduces stretchability, `minus` introduces shrinkability.

Comment: Yes! This worked well and thanks for the explanation.