# Effect of adding plus and minus to \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, calculations, lengths

I have a document with a lot of pictures. The exact scale of the pictures isn't all that important. Is it possible to allow the pictures a little bit of "stretch" to help squeeze everything together? Does adding a plus and minus to the `\includegraphics` as below do anything?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height = 0.5\textwidth plus 3cm minus 3cm]{myimage1}
\includegraphics[height = 0.5\textwidth plus 3cm minus 3cm]{myimage2}
\includegraphics[height = 0.5\textwidth plus 3cm minus 3cm]{myimage3}
\includegraphics[height = 0.5\textwidth plus 3cm minus 3cm]{myimage4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32698/how-to-enable-use-of-minus-and-plus-in-tex-documents

Comment: The `graphicx` package interface keys `height` and `width` expect a dimension not a glue specification. If you tried out your own code you would see it does not work and that the `plus 3cm minus 3cm` ends up printed as text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @jfbu looks like an answer to me:-)

Answer (score 3):

[migrated from comment]

As regards your second question: The `graphicx` package interface keys `height` and `width` expect a dimension, not a glue specification. When one tries out your provided code one sees it does not work and that the `plus 3cm minus 3cm` end up being printed as text.